# Analyser Bars Animation HTML Audio API not working

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-canvas, audiocontext

i used a js code of audio api for visualizing my html5 audio and it worked great here is the tutorial/code

link: https://www.developphp.com/video/Jav...o-API-Tutorial

and it works soo good but the problem when i change the src with external link like:

src= "http://example.com/file.mp3"

the audio dont make sound and the visualization dont show although when i remove the visualization code it work normally... i tried changing

```
context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
```

with

```
AudioContext.createMediaStreamDestination()
```

the audio played but no visualization still.. i don't know what i can do any idea?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*">
<style>
div#mp3_player{ width:500px; height:60px; background:#000; padding:5px; margin:50px auto; }
div#mp3_player > div > audio{  width:500px; background:#000; float:left;  }
div#mp3_player > canvas{ width:500px; height:30px; background:#002D3C; float:left; }
</style>
<script>
// Create a new instance of an audio object and adjust some of its properties
var audio = new Audio();
// audio.crossOrigin='anonymous';
audio.src = 'http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3';
audio.controls = true;
audio.loop = true;
audio.autoplay = true;
// Establish all variables that your Analyser will use
var canvas, ctx, source, context, analyser, fbc_array, bars, bar_x, bar_width, bar_height;
// Initialize the MP3 player after the page loads all of its HTML into the window
window.addEventListener("load", initMp3Player, false);
function initMp3Player(){
 document.getElementById('audio_box').appendChild(audio);
 context = new AudioContext(); // AudioContext object instance
 analyser = context.createAnalyser(); // AnalyserNode method
 canvas = document.getElementById('analyser_render');
 ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 // Re-route audio playback into the processing graph of the AudioContext
 
 source = context.createMediaStreamDestination(audio); 
 
 source.connect(analyser);
 analyser.connect(context.destination);
 frameLooper();

// frameLooper() animates any style of graphics you wish to the audio frequency
// Looping at the default frame rate that the browser provides(approx. 60 FPS)
function frameLooper(){
 window.requestAnimationFrame(frameLooper);
 fbc_array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
 analyser.getByteFrequencyData(fbc_array);
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
 ctx.fillStyle = '#00CCFF'; // Color of the bars
 bars = 100;
 for (var i = 0; i < bars; i++) {
  bar_x = i * 3;
  bar_width = 2;
  bar_height = -(fbc_array[i] / 2);
  //  fillRect( x, y, width, height ) // Explanation of the parameters below
  ctx.fillRect(bar_x, canvas.height, bar_width, bar_height);
 }
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mp3_player">
  <div id="audio_box"></div>
  <canvas id="analyser_render"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably lies in the analyzer node. It can only process media that were loaded in compliance with [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

If the server serving your media is [well configured](http://enable-cors.org/), you may try to set the `crossOrigin` attribute of the audio element, otherwise, you'll have to serve the file from your own domain.

Comment: @Sabreena This is done server side, read the link I gave you in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,got the solution :-)

Comment: @Sabreena , Glad it helped; If the answer helped you to fix your issue, you're more than welcome to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). This way, it will get off of the *to be answered* stream.